# MBTile Example Project - could not find column named tile_data

Tags: xcode4, route-me

I have a problem regarding the implementation of a exported mbtiles file with route-me. I used the example on github and was able to compile and view the example map (control-room).

Now I tried to use an TileMill exported mbtiles file with the example and it did not work. It does not find the tiles for displaying.

I get this error message: Warning: I could not find the column named 'tile_data'.

I think it has to do with the column and row indexes but I was not able to figure out or fix the issue. Does someone have the same experience or a good tutorial for implementing a TileMill export to an iphone application.

Thank you very much in advance.

Thomas

Comment: Problem solved:

I overlooked the the first variables,

    #define kStartingLat
    #define kStartingLon

where you have to define the exact coordinates on the map. I just thought it would some coordinates defined by the map itself, now its working like a charm.